# Profile on meta does not show why a user is suspended

Tags: support, meta, user-accounts, suspension

On a certain meta user's profile, I see:

[image: Meta suspension]

On the main site user profile I see:

[image: Main site suspension]

Why is the reason not shown on meta?

Comment: I know downvotes happen for any and every reason but I am genuinely curious why reporting an apparent bug results in a downvote.

Comment: @Oded - re your tag change; are you saying this is *by design* and not a bug? Can you explain why?

Comment: Pretty  much for the reasons outlined in the answer by Jason. Suspensions do not happen on child-meta sites, only on the parent site (which the child-meta is synced with), but the actual reason only lives on the site that the suspension occurred on.

Comment: A one year suspension. That's certainly quite the cool down period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This (probably) isn't a bug.

This issue was raised recently [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272331/can-the-list-of-reasons-for-temporary-suspension-be-updated-to-properly-reflec/); in [a comment on one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272331/can-the-list-of-reasons-for-temporary-suspension-be-updated-to-properly-reflec/272333#comment884097_272332), animuson said:

> The message didn't change. You were probably looking at your profile on Meta, which doesn't retrieve the sub-reason from the parent site and just doesn't display one.

I'm honestly not sure whether this is considered a bug or a by-design. The most sensible reason I can see for it being by-design is that Meta and Main site data are stored in separate databases, so it's expensive to peek into one from the other; this is why [you can't track the meta badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273010/let-the-convention-badge-be-tracked-as-next-badge) in the new badge tracker thingy.

Then again, this wouldn't be a real-time update, but a single query that could easily be massively cached (not sure how often a suspension reason changes mid-suspension, or if that's possible). So it may be a bug, or it may be a future feature that's not too high on the priority list, or it may just be something the team isn't interested in bothering with.